# MySQL lock wait timeout with a form submit

Tags: java, html, mysql

Here is my doPost method of my servlet that in theory add data in db

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Date d=(Date) request.getAttribute("data");
    DatiAnagrificiImpl dai=new DatiAnagrificiImpl();
    dai.addDatiAnagrafici(new DatiAnagraficiBean(request.getParameter("username"),request.getParameter("cap"),request.getParameter("nome")
                                            ,request.getParameter("cognome"),request.getParameter("telefono"),d));
}
```

And here the method that will insert data in db

```
enter public void addDatiAnagrafici(DatiAnagraficiBean dab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Statement s=c.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("insert into Dati_anagrafici values('"+dab.getIdUtente()+"','"+dab.getIdCittà()+"',"
                        + "'"+dab.getNome()+"','"+dab.getCognome()+"','"+dab.getTelefono()+"','"+dab.getDataNascita()+"')");
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        
    }finally {
        al.add(dab);
    }
}
```

But when I try to do that with a servlet I have this error

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded;

Someone knows how to resolve? If I do the same thing with a normal java class is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a transaction that's not completing. In MySQL, try running these to get a view into what's going on:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

One or both should provide some clues.

A few issues stand out in your code. The first thing I would address is that the `Statement` is never closed (but should be). You can close the statement in a few places, but as the simplest example, you could close it right after you call `executeUpdate()`, like this:

```
Statement s = c.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("...");
s.close();
```

Another easy change: when catching an exception, do something with it (instead of "swallowing" the exception silently). It's possible there's an exception being thrown, but the code above will hide that exception. For example, instead of this:

```
catch (SQLException e) {

}
```

try this:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A final improvement would be to rework the code a bit to use ["try-with-resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) - a nice convenience to automatically close a resource for you (in this case, your `Statement`). That could look like this:

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    statement.executeUpdate("...");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: One more thing.. the `connection` can (and should) be committed by calling [`commit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit--) (or [`rollback()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback--) if something went wrong). Here's a final edit to try which shows `commit()` in the main `try` block, and a `rollback()` in the `catch` block to undo the transaction if an exception is thrown:

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    statement.executeUpdate("...");
    connection.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        connection.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it doesn't work,I retried and I still have 2 Sleep process on db when I submit the form.

Comment: I just posted an edit above to include example for `commit`, that may be the missing piece for you.